# How do you make this code general with loops/recursion? (C)

Tags: c, recursion, fork, pipe

I was wondering how you could make this code general with recursion or a loop.  As of now I just have nested if else statements that do not seem general by any means and would expand and get further indented with more pipes.  The code within the if statements can be generalized and I have no issue with that.  I'm just extremely confused as to how to set up some sort of recursion when the else clause needs to do the if clause if that makes sense.  Here's my code

```
if (fork() == 0)
{
  dup2(pipes[1], 1);
  close(pipes[0]);
  close(pipes[1]);
  close(pipes[2]);
  close(pipes[3]);
  execvp(*cat_args, cat_args);
}
else if (fork() == 0)
{
  dup2(pipes[0], 0);
  dup2(pipes[3], 1);
  close(pipes[0]);
  close(pipes[1]);
  close(pipes[2]);
  close(pipes[3]);
  execvp(*grep_args, grep_args);
}
else if (fork() == 0)
{
  dup2(pipes[2], 0);
  close(pipes[0]);
  close(pipes[1]);
  close(pipes[2]);
  close(pipes[3]);
  execvp(*cut_args, cut_args);
}
```

Comment: You should add at least `exit(1);` (or `_exit(1);`) and possibly an error message after each `execvp()` call. Otherwise, unpleasant things happen when the commands are not executed; you have multiple processes all thinking they should be reading from the terminal, which leads to lots of confusion.

Comment: I mean the code I have here works.  The piping controls the stdout and stdin for the processes.  I'm more or less looking for a way to generalize this code with a loop or recursion.  I just don't know how that works with nested if elses.

Comment: Possible duplicate....?  I'm not asking about pipes.........

Comment: Have you looked at the code in my answer, which deals with a 5-part pipeline using recursion to generalize the process (instead of a mere 3-part pipeline as in your question :D ).  And it would be surprising to find that your `pipes[n]` array is not a set of pipes.

Comment: I'll check it out but what do you mean I did int pipes[4] and then pipe(pipes) and then pipe(pipes+2).  The pipes work, I don't know why you are doubting that.

Comment: OK; you said you weren't asking about pipes...which lead me to suppose you meant that the `pipes` array was not associated with pipes.  The code I mentioned has a pair of mutually recursive functions to process the elements of a pipeline such as yours.  It uses an array of pointers to argument lists rather than separate variables per se — though the code with the hard-wired pipeline does indeed use separate variables and then assembles them into the array.